# Multiple integral question by transformation

Tags: multiple-integral

[image]I have solved this much...how can I integrate now???

Comment: Suppose you show that the integral is less than $1$, then the answer must be b, would that be enough?

Comment: Btw if you have done everything in latex you can post your example here using mathjax with is very similar to latex syntax.

Comment: No, I've done it on a software called "Scientific Workplace"... How can I integrate??